# What is this error installing the Anaconda debugger

Tags: anaconda

I run this script from the Anaconda terminal:

```
conda create -n jupyterlab-debugger -c conda-forge jupyterlab=3 ipykernel>=6 xeus-python
```

and I get this

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: | WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not remove or rename C:\Users\nicomp\anaconda3\envs\jupyterlab-debugger\Lib\site-packages\te
stpath\cli-32.exe.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::pywin32-302-py310he2412df_2'.
Rolling back transaction: done

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\nicomp\\anaconda3\\envs\\jupyterlab-debugger\\Library\\bin\\pythoncom310.dll'
()
```

So it says I need to delete

```
C:\Users\nicomp\anaconda3\envs\jupyterlab-debugger\Lib\site-packages\te
stpath\cli-32.exe
```

but that file isn't on my computer in the first place.